# Django 1.3 Error report remove sensitive information

Tags: python, django

I know django 1.4 has functionality to remove Sensible information in error report.I am using django 1.3 and python 2.4.I want to know whether [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-error-report](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-error-reports)s is back portable to django 1.3 and python 2.4.I tried with no success.please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just copy the sensitive_information decorator to a local decorators.py file, and use it.

```
import functools


def sensitive_variables(*variables):
 """
 Indicates which variables used in the decorated function are sensitive, so
 that those variables can later be treated in a special way, for example
 by hiding them when logging unhandled exceptions.

 Two forms are accepted:

* with specified variable names:

    @sensitive_variables('user', 'password', 'credit_card')
    def my_function(user):
        password = user.pass_word
        credit_card = user.credit_card_number
        ...

* without any specified variable names, in which case it is assumed that
  all variables are considered sensitive:

    @sensitive_variables()
    def my_function()
        ...
"""
 def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if variables:
            wrapper.sensitive_variables = variables
        else:
            wrapper.sensitive_variables = '__ALL__'
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
 return decorator
```

usage:

```
@sensitive_variables('user', 'pw', 'cc')
def my_view(request):
  pass
```

Would need functools.py too, which would not come with python2.4 by default (I guess) -you might have to include that file separately.

Comment: I had tried earlier what you have said.the problem is functools is not supported by python 2.4.