# Django error email is too long. How do I truncate it?

Tags: django, django-errors

It seems like the error emails in Django 1.9 are much longer than they were previously. There's a whole section for "settings" which I think is superfluous and potentially too revealing.

What is the best way to edit the error email that Django sends?

edit: I am not just trying to hide sensitive information. There is a lot more content in the email in Django 1.9 and I want to change the format of the email to be shorter. I liked it the old way.

Comment: did you look here: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-sensitive-information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-sensitive-information)

Comment: This should also put things into perspective for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#debug - All the tokens that contains API, TOKEN, KEY, SECRET, PASS or SIGNATURE will automatically be obscured

Comment: There are two questions which I found similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411362/django-error-reporting-emails-env-vars-leak-info and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301105/django-1-3-error-report-remove-sensitive-information?rq=1 which lead to what @niklas said.

Comment: Hey everyone - I'm not looking to hide sensitive information. The debug email got a lot longer in Django 1.9 and I liked it the way it was before. Where is the template that the email is based on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a django template variable `TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE`/`TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE` in the [django debug view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.5/django/views/debug.py) that controls what's visible in the error reporting, and of course error emails. A comment explains that the template is in a python variable so that errors can be generated in case the template loader breaks. You could change this variable in your django package but I don't recommend that. `TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE` is referenced by the `ExceptionReporter` class in the same file.

The class `AdminEmailHandler` in [django utils log](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.5/django/utils/log.py) then uses the `ExceptionReporter` to generate the html error report.

You can subclass `AdminEmailHandler` and override the `emit` function to include your subclassed version of `ExceptionReporter` that uses your own defined `TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE`.

Here's an example:

Create `reporter.py` with

```
from copy import copy

from django.views import debug
from django.utils import log
from django.conf import settings
from django import template

TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE = """
    # custom template here, copy the original and make adjustments
"""
TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE = """
    # custom template here, copy the original and make adjustments
"""

class CustomExceptionReporter(debug.ExceptionReporter):
    def get_traceback_html(self):
        t = debug.DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE)
        c = template.Context(self.get_traceback_data(), use_l10n=False)
        return t.render(c)

    def get_traceback_text(self):
        t = debug.DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE)
        c = template.Context(self.get_traceback_data(), autoescape=False, use_l10n=False)
        return t.render(c)

class CustomAdminEmailHandler(log.AdminEmailHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            request = record.request
            subject = '%s (%s IP): %s' % (
                record.levelname,
                ('internal' if request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS
                 else 'EXTERNAL'),
                record.getMessage()
            )
        except Exception:
            subject = '%s: %s' % (
                record.levelname,
                record.getMessage()
            )
            request = None
        subject = self.format_subject(subject)

        no_exc_record = copy(record)
        no_exc_record.exc_info = None
        no_exc_record.exc_text = None

        if record.exc_info:
            exc_info = record.exc_info
        else:
            exc_info = (None, record.getMessage(), None)

        reporter = CustomExceptionReporter(request, is_email=True, *exc_info)
        message = "%s\n\n%s" % (self.format(no_exc_record), reporter.get_traceback_text())
        html_message = reporter.get_traceback_html() if self.include_html else None
        self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
```

And then just set your django settings to use your new handler in the [logging section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/).

```
LOGGING = {
    # Your other logging settings
    # ...
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'project.reporter.CustomAdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    },
}
```

If you just want to hide settings you can comment out the `'settings': get_safe_settings(),` line 294, if you override and copy paste `def get_traceback_data(self):` in your `CustomExceptionReporter`

Answer (score 3):

For people still looking for an answer now:

In django 3.0 they added the option to add `reporter_class` which customize **just** the email body, and the traceback text rendering.

So, If you're just looking to change the email template, there's no need to also override the `AdminEmailHandler`.

so based on @Airith answer, you need to have:

```
# custom_exception_reporter.py

from django.views import debug
from django import template

TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE = """ 
# custom template here, copy the original and make adjustments 
"""

class CustomExceptionReporter(debug.ExceptionReporter):
    def get_traceback_text(self):
        t = debug.DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE)
        c = template.Context(self.get_traceback_data(), autoescape=False, use_l10n=False)
        return t.render(c)
```

and then in your log config:

```
'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
             'level': 'ERROR',
             'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
             'include_html': False,
             'reporter_class': 'project.custom_exception_reporter.CustomExceptionReporter'
        },
```

Two notes:

1. If you wish to also send the email body as HTML, you need to have another template - `TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE`, new function - `get_traceback_html()`, and set `include_html = True` in the log configuration. Also here you should copy django's default template and just change what you need.
2. If you don't want to save the entire template in that file, but in a different .html file, notice that even if you will place it inside the template dir you defined, it will not find it. 
   I solved it by keeping the template.html file in the same dir with
   the custom reporter .py file.

example of my custom_exception_report.py, where I keep the template in the same directory (as described in note #2):

```
import os
from django.views import debug
from django import template

TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE = "technical_500.text"


class CustomExceptionReporter(debug.ExceptionReporter):
    def get_traceback_text(self):
        t = self._get_template(TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE)
        c = template.Context(self.get_traceback_data(), autoescape=False, use_l10n=False)
        return t.render(c)

    @staticmethod
    def _get_template(template_name):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        template_path = os.path.join(dir_path, template_name)
        with open(template_path, 'r') as fh:
            return debug.DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
```

You can read more about the report class in django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#id4)