# Django Create Custom Error Report

Tags: django, django-settings

I want to modify the default Django error reporting template [TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/views/debug/)  to provide custom error message. Read doc on modifying the filter tried
`DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'path.to.your.CustomExceptionReporterFilter'` but it's about filtering data but I would like to override the default template itself.

1. Tried  overriding DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER  and defining custom  get_traceback_text and hence passing custom template instead of TECHNICAL_500_TEXT_TEMPLATE in the method.

Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I started noticing the change in the emails after upgrading from 1.7 to 1.9. I used the approach in the following answer. I basically removed the 'settings' section from the templates, including a few other lines that weren't needed.

[Django error email is too long. How do I truncate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165790/django-error-email-is-too-long-how-do-i-truncate-it#answer-36383577)